# Nginx Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and WWW to Non-WWW

Tags: redirect, web, nginx, https

I'm having issues with this config:

```
#=========================#
# domain settings #
#=========================#

# Catch http://domain, and http://www.domain
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain domain;

        # Redirect to https://domain
        return 301 https://domain$request_uri;
}

# Catch https://www.domain
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name www.domain;

        # Redirect to https://domain
        return 301 https://domain$request_uri;
}

# Catch https://domain
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name domain;

        root /usr/share/nginx/domain;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Something is wrong with the 3rd server directive.  I get a SSL connection error.  But when I comment our that section everything works fine.  But I want www to redirect to non-www over https also

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

In the 3rd server directive fixed this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The Nginx configuration snippet below will enable you effectively redirect all http traffic to https while stripping any eventual www prefix.

As such, your site will strictly be available over https and without the www prefix.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    # SSL configuration
    # Other configurations
}
```

With reference to [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), do note that it is safe to use the [if](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) directive as it is not used in a [location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) context.

Comment: How do you handle https certs for https://www.example.com in this setup I still hit a certificate error before the redirect to non www for that version. Cert seems to only apply to non www but cant listen on 443 for www and non in seperate server blocks.

Comment: @GreggoryWiley TLS certificate applies only to the 443 server block; it covers both www and non-www but only serves the non-www. The 80 server block receives receives unencrypted traffic for both www and non-www; it redirects either to only the encrypted non-www only.